# Interesting number sequence puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence

What's the next (last) number in the following sequence?

$1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,\underline{~~?~~}$

(both mathematical and non-mathematical answers are welcome)

Comment: http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2c2%2c3%2c4%2c5%2c6%2c8%2c9%2c10

Comment: It looks to me as if OEIS doesn't contain any sequence beginning that way for which the next number is also the last (which I think is what the "(last)" is intended to mean).

Comment: The statement originally said `What's the next number in the following sequence? (which is also the last one)` and the sequence read `1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,...`. I hope my edit was correct.

Comment: Why was this DVed? Now that I see Jonathan's answer I like it even more.

Comment: I'm sorry for my question being not too interesting in English. I'm Hungarian, so the original question was in Hungarian too. (1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 20, and the answer is 100)

Comment: The English version is extremely interesting in how deceptively boring it looks. Fooled a few voters alright.

Comment: Well yes, I was wondering, if stating, that only non-mathematical answers will be accepted is too much help or not. In my experience (I've told this puzzle to a great many people) saying it aloud helps a lot (which is not too relevant here), but also, answering everyone's first question, which usually is "is this a math question", is of great help to the problem solvers.

Comment: Never too late to add a [`lateral-thinking`](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) tag: `A puzzle solved through an indirect and creative approach, using reasoning that is not immediately obvious and involving ideas that may not be obtainable only using logic`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd plump for

> $12$

Because

> It is the sequence of all positive integers, $\Bbb{N^*}$, that have $1$ syllable in English.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously 11

It is just normal counting

Seven ate nine,so this time nine ate seven so seven isn't there.